# Node.js socket.io returning multiple values for a single event

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm trying to build a simple app using Node, Express (^4.15.3), and socket.io (^2.0.3). I'm building a simple chat app, however each time I add a new message, I get an additional response each time.

For example, if the first message was "Hello", I would be returned:

1. Hello

If I then add a subsequent message of "Is anyone there?", I get back:

1. Is anyone there?
2. Is anyone there?

And so on...each time I get an additional response back.

Here's my code - it feels like it's something really obvious and I may have been staring at it too long...

```
//app.js

var express          = require("express");
var bodyParser       = require("body-parser");
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var session          = require('express-session');
var passport         = require("passport");
var app              = express();
var http             = require('http');
var server           = http.createServer(app);
var io               = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Server starting...");
});

app.get('/testsocket', function(req, res){
   res.render('sockets/test');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Connected')
    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        console.log('Got the message...');
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data) 
    });
});
```

And then client side

```
//client side
$(function() {
  var socket = io.connect();
  var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
  var $messageBox = $('#message');
  var $chat = $('#chat');

  $messageForm.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val());
    $messageBox.val('');

    socket.on('new message', function(data){
      $chat.append(data + "<br>");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're registering the listener for `new message` inside your submit function. So each time you submit the form you register a new listener, in addition to any previous listeners. Try putting the `socket.on('new message', ...` section outside the `submit` handler.